# Animation making a circle

Tags: java, xml, xamarin

I need to create an animation which it will make a full circle around another button.
Can i achieve this using classic animations?
Example giving many translates inside an xml file, with specific offset each one? Or i need to create a specific path for this? I'm new in java so i don't know how to start.
Please check image Below:

[image: Img]

Comment: What does "classic animations" mean ? How are you creating the buttons ?

Comment: I don't know where i should start to search... i thing that i need to create a relative layout and inside to set each button position

Comment: You can use `RotateTo` to  make a full circle around another button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand some trigonometric functions.

```
  /**
     * @static
     * Allows move in circles around given item
     * @param r {float|int} radius in px
     * @param angle {float|int} current angle between circle center and orbiting element
     * @param orbit {object} orbiting el eg. $("#foo")
     * @param speed {int} animation's speed
     * @param [middle=$('#menubutton')] {object} middle of the circle
     */
    static fMenu(r, angle, orbit, speed, middle = Menu.BUTTON) {
        const BY = middle.position().top;
        const BX = middle.offset().left;
        const k = middle.width();
        const KY = middle.height();
        if (angle === 0) {
            angle = 360;
        }
        const x = Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * r;
        const y = Math.tan(Math.PI * angle / 180) * x;
        $(orbit).animate({
            top: (BY - y - KY / 2) + "px",
            left: (BX + x + k / 2 - orbit.width() / 2) + "px",
            opacity: "1"
        }, speed);
    }
```

And you shoud do it in loop or setTimeout/setInterval. I've made this code some time ago **for jQuery**, but you get the idea? - Most important are lines with `Math.cos` and `Math.tan`.

Comment: I think that math is existing in ValueAnimator.

Comment: Possible, there are a lot of animation libraries, which are able to make orbit animation.